# How do I style ggplot caption?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this ggplot chart

```
ggplot(
  data = cars,
  aes(
    x = dist,
    y = speed
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    caption = "Some caption"
  )
```

How do I change the color of the caption and make it italicized.

Comment: For simple changes to the whole caption, I think the `plot.caption()` theme element may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust it with `+ theme(plot.caption = element_text(color = "red", face="italic"))`